# Is it possible to have TWIG translate the templates using YAML files

Tags: php, templates, twig, translation

I have TWIG templates with a plain PHP site, and I would like to load translated YAML files, like I do with a similar Silex project. However, I don't see anything in the Twig documentation about translations other than gettext, and I don't understand how to add the Symfony YamlFileLoader into plain Twig.

Is this possible, or is gettext the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translation isn't part of Twig.

Silex uses [Symfony2 Translation Component](https://github.com/symfony/Translation) which provides support for translations in YAML files. You must install and configure that component and then register twig extension so you can use it in Twig. Twig integration for translation component is part of [TwigBridge](https://github.com/symfony/TwigBridge).